# How to add a scrollable area in a Konva stage?

Tags: html, scroll, stage, konvajs

I am trying to create a web application and I am using Konva for this because it makes it easier with grouping objects and drag&drop. Now I want to create an area (or multiple) that is individually scrollable, like it happens when you add the `overflow: scroll` property to the style of a `div`.

I have tried to create two `Konva.Stage` objects and set the `overflow: scroll` property, but I couldn't make it work, only the first stage would appear.

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="block"></div>

<style>
    div.container {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }

    div.block {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: scroll;
        background-color: #0000ff;
    }

</style>
```

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height/2
});

var stage2 = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'block',
    width: width,
    height: height/2
});
```

What is the solution for creating a scrollable area?

Comment: What exactly do you want to make scrollable? Two large stages but inside smaller containers each of them are draggable? Or one small and scrollable container with two stages inside?

Comment: I would want one stage with scrollable elements inside. For example, a stage with scrollable Konva.Rect elements. The reason I created 2 stages was that I did not know how else to make an element scrollable, but I would prefer not using multiple stages.

Comment: Did you look here? https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Canvas_Scrolling.html#How-to-display-and-scroll-a-very-big-html5-canvas

Comment: yes, but it doesn't really help

Answer (score 1):

To make a scrollable area you can just create a large stage, but put it inside a smaller container with `overflow: auto`

```js
// create large stage
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth * 2,
  height: window.innerHeight * 2
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const circle = new Konva.Circle({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  radius: 150,
  fill: 'green'
});
layer.add(circle);

layer.draw();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^2/konva.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="stage"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain correctly, I am sorry for the confusion. What I want is the object (e.g., a circle) to be inside a scrollable area that is inside this big scrollable Konva Stage area. Just like in the first example here: [overflow CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow), a small scrollable area inside a bigger scrollable area.

Comment: That is a complex task. You will have to create a clipped group and implement all scrolling manually (draw scrollbars, move then, etc).